# Top 3 API gateway middle ware tools for managing multiple REST API's

Tags: windows, open-source, security

**Use Case:**

1. **Authentication and Authorization (Multi Tenant Support):** 
   We have multiple REST API's resource with their own
   authentication and authorization business logic. Most of them have
   firm-wide accepted standard for authentication framework like LDAP for
   authentication and Active Directory for Authorization but there are quite a 
   number which are using their own databases or systems for authentication and 
   own logic for authorization. There should be centralize system 
   (middleware/gateway) which will 
   on board REST API's and provide standard authentication and authorization 
   mechanism with minimum overhead for client to authorize at their end. Client 
   could be on any platform.
2. **Orchestration :** Considering end users requirements, there exists scenarios where data from 
   needs multiple API's have to merged and expose new endpoint all together as 
   new API. There should be orchestration between API's that are already been 
   exposed.
3. **Extra Features:** Middle-ware should posses features such as  Highly Available, fault 
   tolerant and scalable,Traffic control, limit request for specific API's.
4. **Centralize Logging:**  Need logging functionality for each and every action performed on middle- 
   ware by any client.
5. **Data Transformation:** Client may require data been exposed as API's in different format viz json, 
   xml,doc, excel, pdf
6. **Analytics:** support for middle-ware in terms of number of requested for any 
   API's, Failed login tries, analytics around resources been used.

I have googled and found following tools for perusal, but it is practically impossible to do POC on below listed tools. I want help in evaluation of below tools as i have gathered basic details for following tools just by googling. Could anyone suggest top 3 tools which will cater all above mentioned use cases.

1. Kong
2. Apigee
3. 3scale
4. IBM API Connect
5. Akana
6. Dell Boomi
7. Mashery
8. MuleSoft (Anypoint)
9. WSO2

**Note: You can suggest any other open source or commercial tools which you have used and find it could suffice the above mentioned use case will be appreciated**